# Multiple data in foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

I'm searching a solution for register multiples var in a foreach loop.

Example: I have an array with a size of 150. I want to have the first 50 results, and the 51 - 100 results and 101 - 150 result at the end in different vars.
My array is in constant searching so if I can stop the request, it's better!

```
$data = A html parser .
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $html->load_file($data[$i]);
    $donnees = $html->find('br table[width="100%"],[border="1"]');
    foreach ($donnees as $donnee) {
        foreach ($donnee->find('a[href]') as $href) {
            $dataLien[] = $href->href;
            }
    }
}
```

Thx for ur answers

Comment: Please make your question clear

Comment: your code is very vague, more details needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create 3 array then define size limit

```
$array0=array();
$array1=array();
$array2=array()

$result= // add your result in this variable

$i=1;

$saveItemPerArray = 50;

$noArray = 0;
foreach($result as $data){

    if(($i % $saveItemPerArray) == 0){
        $noArray++;
    }

    array_push($array.$noArray,$data)

    $i++;
}
```